# Image won't Display in HTML

Tags: html, image

i have something weird with my script
here

```html
<img scr="test.jpg" alt="TEST" width="200" height="200">
```

The image location is same as html file, but its show nothing just the alt

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change `scr` to `src` and it should work.

Comment: ah thanks, jeez i like a fool, i runs out the time and anything gone wrong haha.

Comment: I've made a few typos myself...it happens.

Comment: :-) beginner to advanced you always make these types of mistakes don't feel bad